# How can I get all objects with a timestamp greater than X from an EF repo?

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, timestamp

I have a timestamp (rowversion) column (called t_stamp) in my tables. I use EF4 as my ORM. I see that the timestamp fields become byte[] properties on my objects.

I want to use LINQ something like this:

```
byte[] last = 0x00782342

from o in _db.Objects
where o.t_stamp > last
select o
```

But that doesn't work because I can't use > on a byte[].

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I suggest then that the problem you are really experiencing is really a LINQ question.  Perhaps try adding LINQ as a tag and removing the sql tag.

Comment: I'm going to remove my answers.  Maybe you'll get a better look at it.

Comment: @MaasSql - Thanx, I still haven't found a solution so for now I'm using a datatime field (which I find a bit icky...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Querying a timestamp column from LINQ to SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547684/querying-a-timestamp-column-from-linq-to-sql)

Comment: Not sure why you find a datetime field "icky" because that is what you need. The term "timestamp" in SQL Server is NOT related in any way to date or time (& that's why MS are trying to teach us to use the term "rowversion" instead) . In SQL Server: datetime or datetime2 columns are used for storing (real) timestamps

Comment: A bit of a late reaction, but a timestamp/rowversion column is guaranteed to change for each row. Datetime doesn't. Here I was trying to make sure I didn't process records twice.

Comment: I sure would appreciate it if somewhere where to answer the question. I'm pretty new to LINQ and after an hour of googling still have no idea how to utilize rowversion to find updated rows